# Export everything from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to export everything(users, roles, object definitions, data) from my PostgreSQL and restore it into another server. How can I do that?

I try to use

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -g > out.sql
```

but file **out.sql** is empty. Can someone explain me why this happens?

When I try:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres > out.sql
```

PostgreSQL just didn't want to accept password for "postgres".

I prefer to do this job from (windows) command line(it is not problem and with linux command, I can translate them). And if there is nice pgAdmin way to do it, I will happy to learn it, too.

### P.S: My password for "postgres" is correct (I try to login with "psql -U postgres" and there is no problem)

Update: I try with user different than "postgres"(in this case **rsmn**):

```
pg_dumpall -U rsmn > out.sql
```

I have following error:

> pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR: permission dneied for relation
>   pg_authid pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper,
>   rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit,
>   rolpassword, rolvalidunil, rolreplication, rolbypassrls,
>   pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname
>   = current_user as is_current_user FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname !~ '^pg_' ORDER BY 2

User privileges(This user is only one beside "postgres"):
[image]

Comment: If the output is empty, you probably got an error. Find the error message, it will help you!

Comment: Excuse me, I was missed **-g** flag and without his, it just didn't want to accept my password. In command prompt there isn't error massage! Where can I find "log" file?

Comment: There will be an error message in case of error. Maybe `pg_dumpall` waited for you to enter a password?

Comment: Yes, it wait for me to enter a password and:
 - in case "pg_dumpall -U postgres -g > out.sql" after i enter a password, i have empty file
- in case "pg_dumpall -U postgres > out.sql" it didn't accept my password and prompt me again and again

Comment: I try with other user and I have error! I update my post with this error!

Comment: The easy way out there is to make `rsmn` a superuser temporarily so it has access to everything. But that's just deferring the problem, you'll still have something strange with authenticating as `postgres`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do it under the *nix and your server is installed localy, you may not to use `ident` mode instead of `password`:

```
sudo su postgres
pg_dumpall > out.sql
```

Comment: What is `indent` mode?

Comment: Have a look to the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html (auth-method). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT

Comment: Oh, you meant `ident`.

Answer (score 0):

The attempt with user `rsmn` fails because it is not a superuser and cannot export the user passwords.

It remains to figure out why `pg_dumpall -U postgres` fails for you.

For that, the first thing would be to check the PostgreSQL server log. I am not sure where that is on your system, you should check the settings in `postgresql.conf` (`logging_collector`, `log_destination`, `log_directory`, `log_filename`). Probably it is in the Windows Event Log.

The log message will tell you what is wrong.

It could well be a problem with the `pg_hba.conf` file – if so, modern PostgreSQL versions will tell you which line was used.

For debugging purposes, you can try to change the relevant line to `trust` authentication so that no password is requested (but don't leave it that way, or everybody can connect as user `postgres` without password!).